# How to get maximum version of record from each set using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following student list:

```
IList<Student> studentList = new List<Student>()
{ 
    new Student() { StudentID = 1, StudentName = "John", Age = 13 ,Version = 1, Group = 1},
    new Student() { StudentID = 2, StudentName = "Moin", Age = 21 ,Version = 2, Group = 1},
    new Student() { StudentID = 3, StudentName = "Bill", Age = 18, Version = 1, Group = 2},
    new Student() { StudentID = 4, StudentName = "Ram", Age = 20, Version = 1, Group = 3},
    new Student() { StudentID = 5, StudentName = "Ron", Age = 15, Version = 1, Group = 5},
    new Student() { StudentID = 6, StudentName = "yim", Age = 25, Version = 2, Group = 5},
};
```

How do I get a list which contains the maximum version of each group? What is the suitable LINQ query?

The output should look like:

```
{ StudentID = 2, StudentName = "Moin", Age = 21, Version = 2, Group = 1 },
{ StudentID = 3, StudentName = "Bill", Age = 18, Version = 1, Group = 2 },
{ StudentID = 4, StudentName = "Ram", Age = 20, Version = 1, Group = 3 },
{ StudentID = 6, StudentName = "yim", Age = 25, Version = 2, Group = 5 },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
var results = studentList.GroupBy(x => x.Group)
                         .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(xx => xx.Version).First())
                         .ToList();
```

Group them by `Group`, then order the groupings by the `Version` descending, and grab the first off the grouping.

Comment: Upvoted. However, if there are many elements in each group, sorting repeatedly will be expensive. A function could be provided that grabs the student with the max version in O(n)

Comment: Couldn't you `OrderBy(x => x.Group).ThenByDescending(x => x.Version)` Then do the GroupBy select. Edit: then the answer is `studentList.OrderBy(x => x.Group).ThenByDescending(x => x.Version).GroupBy(x => x.Group).Select(x => x.First())`

Comment: This of course does not work in EF Core, so removing the tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var maxStudents = (from s in studentList
                    group s by s.Version into g
                    select new 
                    {
                      Version = g.Key,
                      MaxAge = g.Max(s => s.Age)
                    }).ToList();
// You'll be left with an array like: [{Version=1, MaxAge=21},...]
```